# Why Decimal from String return value without well formatted input?

Tags: swift, string, decimal

In my case I have string with coma.

```
var stringWithComa = "1,2"
```

When I try to convert it to `Float` or `Double` I receive `nil` as expected.

```
Float(stringWithComa)//nil

Double(stringWithComa)//nil
```

But when I do `Decimal(string: stringWithComa)` I receive  `1`.

Why this issue is happening ?

Comment: Apparently `Decimal(string:)` just stops parsing as soon as an invalid character is found. `Decimal(string: "1.23")` returns `1.23` without exploding.

Comment: @MartinR I am a bit confused due to that implementation. Because seams to me in method Decimal(string:) implementation  they also take current locale of the user but without respecting of the locale decimal separator.

Comment: If you want to the the current locale into account then you'll have to call `Decimal(string: stringWithComma, locale: .current)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Decimal(string:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal/1780123-init) to parse a string containing a localized
number. Example:

```
print(Locale.current.decimalSeparator!) // ","

let stringWithComma = "1,2"
if let dec = Decimal(string: stringWithComma, locale: .current) {
    print(dec) // 1.2
}
```

Otherwise the comma is considered as an invalid character.
Contrary to the `Float` and `Double` initializers, leading whitespace
and trailing “junk” is ignored. The conversion succeeds if at least
one valid character was found:

```
print(Decimal(string: "   1.23")) // Optional(1.23)
print(Decimal(string: "")) // nil
```

Answer (score 1):

The Decimal(string: String) constructor in swift will keep on parsing the provided string. If It finds any invalid character which cannot be evaluated, it will stop parsing.

A few examples -

> Decimal(string: "34234.43423.4343") => "34234.43423"
>
> Decimal(string: "#343.43") => nil